# Symmetric term for engaging with someone over SMS or Email

Tags: terminology

I want to make a natural language question answering that can answer

> when did I speak with Raj
>   when did I Talk to Raj

This term *speak* is symmetrical, it is not implied who initiated the call; while "A texted B" is directed. I want a similar phrase for:

> [Message/ Email with] Raj

that is also symmetrical. Being a phrase users have to utter themselves, it must be memorable for them.

Comment: Maybe this can help? [Synonyms for messaging](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/messaging/)

Comment: If you can provide context about where the term will be used, we can give better answers. For example, in journalism you're likely to see terms like "correspond", "communicate", or maybe "converse" for email/sms. Whereas in a UI you'd probably go for something more concise, plus visual cues to reinforce the mode of communication.

Comment: @NoahC, Vitaly, sorry for not providing context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example,

> "When did I speak with Raj"

you are the one doing the speaking, but the idea is that both of you are talking together. The expression "speak **with**" emphasizes that.

So, you could just as easily say

> "When did I **text with** Raj"

to mean that you and Raj sent text messages with each other.

The preposition "with", in this case, enforces the idea that two people are engaged in an action without implying who initiated or is leading the action. You could also say

- email with
- Skype with
- SMS with (European alternative to text with)
- chat with
- Facetime with (for iphoners)

and people will understand the reciprocal nature of your communique.

Answer (score 1):

If it's informal you could say *'messaged'* - the implication with that particular word is that regardless of medium it was a brief message.

Comment: But the question is not about that.. Sorry if my earlier edit was confusing.